# How to calculate the weight individual fractions to equal the weighting of the product of the same fractions

Tags: fractions, products

What is the formula to apply a weighting to 2 fractions individually to get the same answer if you weight their product?  In the example below 50% * 100% = 50%.  Multiplied times 80% (weighting) the answer is 40%.  What formula can be used to multiply 50% and 100% individually to also arrive at 40% when you multiply the result.  Example: (50% * A) = X and (100% * B) = Y; and X * Y = 40%.  I am looking for the formula to arrive at A and B.

Value 1 50.0%
Value 2 100.0%
Product of 1 and 2  50.0%
Weighting   80%
Weighting * Product 40%

Weighting
A?  X = Value 1 * Weighting A
B?  Y = Value 2 * Weighting B
    X * Y = 40%

Comment: The question's phrasing is a bit difficult to follow, could you try to re-phrase the question? The last line is specially confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one answer.

So for example if A=80% and B=100% then you have (50% * 80%) * (100% * 100%) = 40%

Or if A=100% and B=80% then you have (50% * 100%) * (100% * 80%) = 40%

Or if A=B=89.4427191% then you have (50% * 89.4427191%) * (100% * 89.4427191%) = 40% or very close to it, noting that $\sqrt{0.8} \approx 0.894427191$.

The only important thing is that A*B=80%, since multiplication is commutative.

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking for the number where A=B, but did not specify.  I appreciate the help.